# T-SQL Window Functions with CTE, use previously computed value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, window-functions

I tried to calculate values in the Result field that reference to previous Result value using the following CTE Query:

```
WITH cteA (N, val1) AS (
    SELECT 1, 5.1 UNION
    SELECT 2, 6.5 UNION
    SELECT 3, 7.5 UNION
    SELECT 4, 4.6 UNION
    SELECT 5, 3.2
), cteB AS (
    SELECT *
        , val1 / LAG(val1) OVER (ORDER BY N) val2
        , (CASE N WHEN 1 THEN 100 END) result
    FROM cteA
)

SELECT *
FROM cteB
```

It returns unexpected *NULL* values on the Result field:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeMcO.png

I need help to get the expected values instead of *NULL*s as follow:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XprEW.png

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use recursive cte

```
with
cteR AS
(
    SELECT  N, val1, 
            val2   = convert(decimal(20,4), NULL), 
            result = convert(decimal(20,4), 100)
    FROM    cteA
    WHERE   N   = 1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  a.N, a.val1, 
            val2   = convert(decimal(20,4), a.val1 / r.val1), 
            result = convert(decimal(20,4), a.val1 / r.val1 * r.result)
    FROM    cteR r
            INNER JOIN cteA a   on  r.N = a.N - 1

)
SELECT  *
FROM    cteR
```